# Prevent Duplicate Borders on Nested Table (border-collapse not working)

Tags: css, nested, html-table, border

I have been searching the net about border-collapse. And it seems it does not really collapse the border on nested table. I wrote a sample HTML and it seems to be ignoring border collapse.

I found a related question here but it seems it is not solved. [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049701/nested-tables-1px-border-with-css)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>dsafhidsljfalkdsjfklsdajfkjsdakl jdsfjasdklfasdkljfkl</p>
  <table style="border: solid 1px #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="border: solid 1px #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              A
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              B
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Supplementary Info (based on somacore and moo's comment): 
I already used the "border: none" in the internal table to solve this problem. But on some designs, it is not just one nested table. For complex web pages, it needs upto 3 to 4 nested table levels to design the GUI. And inside those nested tables, not all cells uses border. I had just used a simple example for the problem.

Is there any other solution that hand picking merging adjacent borders to  one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

border-collapse works on the td and tr elements within a table.

And like somacore stated... why not turn off the border on the second table? (or why not use real markup?)